# Is the license of gifmerge compatible with GPLv3?

Tags: licensing, gpl

My doubt arises from this sentence in the gifmerge distribution conditions:

"This software may be freely copied, modified and redistributed without fee provided that this copyright notice is preserved intact on all copies and modified copies."

Especially the "without fee" part is the one thet puzzle me.

Can some expert dispel my doubt?

http://www.the-labs.com/GIFMerge/

Comment: Can you link to the actual license, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. For reference, take a look at [this](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#UtahPublicLicense) link, which is the FSF's stance on a similar license. Prohibiting commercial redistribution makes it non-free software.

Comment: I forgot that there was a very similar case in the quiz here that confirm that: http://www.gnu.org/cgi-bin/license-quiz.cgi